# Vuetify remove dialog's box shadow

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to remove the box-shadow from the dialog box of vuetify. Image of that -->
[image]

In chrome devTools if I set box-shadow to none it works. Like the image below.
[image]

But when I am adding a class with box-shadow none, it ain't working. Code for that-->

```
    <v-dialog
      v-model="assignedPRPaneldialog"
      width="700"
      content-class="vDialog"
    >
      <v-card v-if="GET_PRESS_RELEASE_ASSIGNED_DATA.length > 0">
        <!-- {{ GET_PRESS_RELEASE_ASSIGNED_DATA }} -->
        <v-card
          v-for="(item, i) in GET_PRESS_RELEASE_ASSIGNED_DATA"
          :key="i"
          class="pa-2"
          outlined
        >
          <CardPr :simple="true" :item="item" />
        </v-card>
      </v-card>
      <v-card v-else>
        <v-alert border="bottom" colored-border type="warning" elevation="0">
          No Press Release yet.
        </v-alert>
      </v-card>
   </v-dialog>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  div.vDialog {
     box-shadow: none;
  }
</style>
```

What should I do here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is how I removed it in the demo: https://codepen.io/Manoj6994/pen/vYZyzZK https://nimb.ws/4o3vpB Targetting `.v-dialog` is enough but I used an ID so that it works for that specific dialog.

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion took me to the right path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following m4n0's suggestion, found out any class that I use on v-dialog component was applying in the dialog inside v-application--wrap. But as you can see outside application--wrap, there is another v-dialog class is appearing. So currently I removed the scoped property from style, which is now giving me my desired output. Probably targeting the class should be a better option. I will try that out later.
[image]

I am not sure though if it is an intended behavior or I made a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

There are two easy ways I know of to remove box-shadow from v-dialog (and v-menu).

**1. Globally:**

```
<style>
.v-dialog {
  box-shadow: none;
}
</style>
```

**2. Specific v-dialog (better way):**

```
<v-dialog content-class="elevation-0">
...
</v-dialog>
```

Notice that it has to be `content-class` instead of just `class`.
And if you want to hide the overlay, too:

```
<v-dialog content-class="elevation-0" hide-overlay>
...
</v-dialog>
```

References:
[v-dialog API](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-dialog/), [Vuetify Elevation helpers](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/elevation/)

Answer (score 0):

From this code it's visible that shadow is added on element with .v-dialog class, so you're adding "no-shadow" style to the wrong element.

```
.v-dialog {
border-radius: 6px;
margin: 24px;
overflow-y: auto;
pointer-events: auto;
transition: 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.25, 1);
width: 100%;
z-index: inherit;
box-shadow: 0px 11px 15px -7px rgb(0 0 0 / 9%), 0px 24px 38px 3px rgb(0 0 0 / 5%), 0px 9px 46px 8px rgb(0 0 0 / 3%);
```

You can add your class directly to `<v-dialog>` component, or use `elevation-0` class.

EDIT:
If you want to remove dialog's overlay, use [hide-overlay](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-dialog/#props-hide-overlay) prop

Comment: hide-overlay doesn't remove the shadow. It gives a white shadow. I want the gray shadow gone. elevation-0 doesn't change anything here. I used inline style which also didn't remove the shadow. I didn't get the wrong element part here. Cause I used vDialog class. but if you look at elements image, my class is shown in the element. So it should apply I think

Comment: @HimuraDaBattosuai Shadow and overlay are two different things, I'm not exactly sure what's your goal here. I often use custom CSS as in m4n0 's codepen example. In my answer I wrote that if you want to remove the shadow from your dialog you should target the correct HTML element since you were adding CSS property to the wrong one. In the end that was your solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<v-dialog>
 <v-card class="elevation-0"> //<- this code use
 ...
 </v-card>
</v-dialog>
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**